# Issue while converting pandas to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I'm converting string to datetime datatype using pandas,
here is my snippet,

```
df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%H%M%S%d%m%Y', errors='coerce')
```

input :

```
col
00000001011970
00000001011970
...
00000001011970
```

output:

```
col
1970-01-01
1970-01-01
...
1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

the ouput consists of date and date with time..
I need the output as date with time.
PLease help me out where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

The time is there. It just so happens, because it's midnight, `00:00:00`, it is not showing explicitly.

You can see it's with e.g.

```
df[col].dt.minute
```

which will give a Series of 0's.

To print out the time explicitly, you could use

```
df[col].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Alter the format as you see fit.

---

Keep in mind that the visual output with anything in Pandas (or computers in general) does not have to be exactly what is stored. It is up to the programmer to format the output into what they want. But calculations on the variables still uses all (invisible) information.

Comment: your code converts datetime datatype to object , and i need date time datatype

Comment: No: the `.dt` attribute contains a full-blown datetime object. Are you looking at just the string output? Because that may look like an `object`. But again, read my answer; and my comment. Or check `df[col].dtype`.

Comment: raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. Did you mean: 'at'?-->got error like this

Comment: @user You should obviously run `df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%H%M%S%d%m%Y', errors='coerce')` before using `df[col].dt`.

Comment: i got the same output as i mentioned in my question

Answer (score -1):

Just like the other answer suggested time is there, but since it's midnight 00:00:00, it's not showing explicitly. To print out the date with time you can try this :

```
df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%H%M%S%d%m%Y', errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: your code converts datetime datatype to object , and i need date time datatype